# HtmlEditorExtender image upload doesn't work on server (internet explorer)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-7, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have developed the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="headerPopupFixed">
        <label class="tituloPopup">
            Edição da ajuda</label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSalvar" Text="Salvar" runat="server" OnClick="btnSalvar_OnClick"
            CssClass="botao" />
    </div>
    <div class="filtroPopup">
        <div class="row">
            <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptmanger" runat="server" CombineScripts="false" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHelp" Width="600px" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="25" />
            <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="heeHelp" runat="server" EnableSanitization="false"
                DisplaySourceTab="true" TargetControlID="txtHelp" ClientIDMode="Inherit" OnImageUploadComplete="heeHelp_OnImageUploadComplete">
                <Toolbar>
                    <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
                    <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
                    <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
                    <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
                    <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
                    <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
                    <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
                    <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
                    <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
                    <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
                    <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
                    <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
                    <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
                    <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
                    <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
                    <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
                    <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
                    <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
                    <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
                </Toolbar>
            </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Wich works just fine in my local machine for any browser. It works great even after publishing and accessing it by IIS (again, in my computer).

But after I Ctrl+c Ctrl+v the publishing into the server I get an error when I try to upload an image with Internet Explorer (Chrome works fine). 
I tried this in two different servers (2008 and 2012) with IIS7 and IIS8 and got the same result with IE 10 and 11.

I guess it's something related to the server enviroment, or IIS configuration. But not sure what.

The error message is "SCRIPT5022: error raising upload complete event and start new upload"

I have also noticed that in my local machine CSS is rendered correctly, and when published on these servers they are not perfect as if there some compatibility issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, after a lot of struggling I found out that the problem was a tag in the web.config

```
<authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Thanks Internet Explorer =P